# PHP Pulling from SQL and then selecting a specific ID

Tags: php, mysql

So I have pulled all information from MySQL with PHP by searching for all rows where the ID is equal to an ID that matches a specific user.

I've then displayed it with a while loop into a nice table. At the end of the table I've added a form with a button to delete the row.

Now, I'm not sure how to accomplish this and I'm not sure what to really search for on the web, but I want the button to delete the specific row that is displayed, but i'm displaying many rows and so the delete button really just deletes the last displayed row. I've tried putting it into an array but that just does the same thing as well.

How might I be able to accomplish this so it deletes the specific row that it is accompanied with? Because Ive generated this button iteratively its essentially useless.

Also the form is set to GET so I could see the error that was occurring in what was passed.

```
    if($logquery->num_rows){
    while($logquery->fetch()){
        echo "<table><tr><th>Date</th></tr>
                <tr><td>".$date."</td></tr>
                <tr><th>User</th></tr>
                <tr><td>".$user."</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Log</th></tr>
                <tr><td><p>".$log."</p></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Comment</th></tr>
                <tr><td>".$comment."</td></tr>
                <tr><td><form action='viewuser.php' method='get'>
                        <input style='display: none;' type='text' name='delog_' id='delog' value='".$log_id."'>
                        <input type='submit' name='delsub' value='Delete?'>
                        <form></td></tr>
                </table><br>
        ";

    }
}
```

On delete:

```
if(isset($_GET['delsub'])){
    $delquery = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM logs WHERE log_id = ? ");
    $delquery->bind_param("i", $_GET['delog_']);
    $delquery->execute();
    echo "Log Delete. Returning to user search";
    header("refresh:5; users.php");
}
```

Query:

```
$logquery = $con->prepare(" SELECT * FROM logs WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY log_id DESC ");
        $logquery->bind_param("s", $userid);
        $logquery->execute();
        $logquery->store_result();
        $logquery->bind_result($log_id, $user_id, $log, $date, $user, $comment);
```

Comment: Use `type="hidden"` for hidden inputs.

Comment: Do you really want to create a new table for each row of results, rather than just a table row?

Comment: Where is `$log_id` (or any of the other variables for that matter) being populated? It isn't clear. There's no obvious link between that and the query result. Have you bound it somewhere? If so please show us the code so we are clear.

Comment: What's your DELETE statement? BTW, you should probably set `<input type="hidden"...` instead of `type="text"` with `style="display:none;"`. Also, with such loop, you are creating new table for every row.

Comment: @barmar thank you! I didn't realize hidden was a type. I was just displaying it as rows but how I have it set currently looks the best, may change it back though.

Comment: @ADyson Since this is mysqli, they're presumably set with `$logquery->bind_result()`

Comment: Just edit your original post, please.

Comment: @cyborg86pl sorry about that, edited

Comment: It might have been easier than expected, seems like you have another `<form>` opening tag instead of closing one `</form>` so technically there is only one form with just last `$log_id` value, overrided many times.

Comment: @cyborg86pl omg your absolutely right I corrected it and it works just fine now... Thank you! I thought the $log_id variable was updating constantly and so after it was done iterating it was the value of the last iteration. But it seems working just fine now!

Comment: @Barmar I guessed as much...but wanted to check whether perhaps a mistake had been made in that process, for example. Anyway looks like it was nothing to do with it in the end.

Comment: @DFLEX please don't update your question to show the solution - it makes a nonsense of the question/answer format. I've rolled back your change. The accepted answer below already explains the solution to anyone reading, and they are likely to want to compare it to what the code originally looked like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another `<form>` opening tag instead of closing one.

That is why you can only delete row that matches last log id - there is technically only one form with multiple `input`s named `delog_`. Performing click on any of submit buttons sends that last, overrided id.

It's equivalent to:

```
<form action="viewuser.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="delog_" id="delog" value="1"> <!-- overrided -->
    <input type="submit" name="delsub" value="Delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="delog_" id="delog" value="2"> <!-- overrided -->
    <input type="submit" name="delsub" value="Delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="delog_" id="delog" value="3"> <!-- overrided -->
    <input type="submit" name="delsub" value="Delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="delog_" id="delog" value="4"> <!-- last id, actually sent -->
    <input type="submit" name="delsub" value="Delete">
</form>
```